# what is wrong with here parseInt() method.?

Tags: java

```
import javax.swing.*;

class gui {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Scanner obj = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = " ";
        s = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "enter first value");
        String ab = s;
        int value1 = Integer.parseInt(ab);

        String s2 = " ";
        s2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "enter second value");
        String cd = s2;
        int value2 = Integer.parseInt(cd);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " the result " + (value1 + value2));

    }
}
```

Comment: What's the error you are seeing?

Comment: Also, why do you have `String s = " ";` then overwrite it with the input dialog? Why don't you just do `String s = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "enter first value");`? Same goes with `s2`.

Comment: error  = error cannot find symbol

Comment: error = cannot find a symol

Comment: Please edit your Q and post as much detail as possible on the error. Copy/paste from the error console if you have to.

Comment: i do before this String s = JOptionpane.showInputDialoge(null,"enter first value"); but error is come same lines. thats  whay i m using antoher way.

Comment: You code compiles fine for me...

Comment: plz dear can u send me error free my program to see what m do wrong

Comment: I copied and pasted your code into my IDE and works fine

Comment: can u end me again fine program of which you did in you ide.

Answer (score 1):

`Integer.parseInt()` can throw an `NumberFormatException`, i.e. `Integer.parseInt("abc")`. Whilst you don't have to catch it (it's an unchecked exception), you should make sure your code can handle such input. For example, if you do handle it with a `catch`:

```
try {
   Integer.parseInt(ab);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
   // Handle exception i.e. display error
}
```

Please check out the documentation on `Integer.parseInt` [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)).

Also please see this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115896/java-checked-vs-unchecked-exception-explanation) for useful information on unchecked exceptions and why in this case (working with UI) you should probably catch it.

Comment: `NumberFormatException` is an unchecked exception (extending from `RuntimeException`), it doesn't "have" to be caught

Comment: @MadProgrammer, ah I didn't realise that. Thanks! +1 I'll edit the answer appropriately.